# Avada Wordpress Theme: Container Background not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So, I have been working with Avada attempting to create a one page scrolling site and for some reason when I assign a container in fusion builder a background image or background colour, it doesnt show. It just shows the main background colour from the Avada settings.

Is there anyway around this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll find that you get far better answers here if you help people to help you by including specific code that shows your problem. There's good advice in the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. I'd recommend reading that, then coming back and editing your question to take into account the suggestions there.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact the theme author.

You have dedicated support for matters such as this: https://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226/support